# Dropping a MKPinAnnotationView with animation

Tags: iphone

I'm confused on how this works.  I'm creating a CLGeocoder to drop a pin based on a string value.  I have this:

```
- (void)placeMarkFromString:(NSString *)address {
    CLGeocoder *geocoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];
    [geocoder geocodeAddressString:address completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {
        [placemarks enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
            NSLog(@"%@", [obj description]);
        }];

        // Check for returned placemarks
        if (placemarks && [placemarks count] > 0) {
            CLPlacemark *topResult = [placemarks objectAtIndex:0];

            // Create an MKPlacemark and add it to the mapView
            MKPlacemark *place = [[MKPlacemark alloc] initWithPlacemark:topResult];
            AddressAnnotation *anAddress = [[AddressAnnotation alloc] init];
            anAddress.address = place.subThoroughfare;
            anAddress.street = place.thoroughfare;
            anAddress.city = place.locality;
            anAddress.state = place.administrativeArea;
            anAddress.zip = place.postalCode;
            anAddress.name = place.name;

            //[self.mapView addAnnotation:place];
            [self.mapView addAnnotation:anAddress];
            self.currentPlacemark = place;

            // Center map on that region
            MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(topResult.location.coordinate, 2000, 2000);
            MKCoordinateRegion adjustedRegion = [_mapView regionThatFits:region];
            [_mapView setRegion:adjustedRegion animated:YES];
        }
        else {
            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"No Results Found" message:@"" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles: nil];
            [alert show];
        }
        if (error) {
            NSLog(@"Error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
        }
    }];
}
```

So originally, I added my MKPlacemark to the map and it shows the red pin.  It does not animate however.  I basically want the ability to drop any of the 3 MKPinAnnotationView colors, have a callout and the title/subtitle to be the name and address of the place, similar to how google maps does it.  But I was not getting any animation.

So I thought that maybe I needed to create my own object that conforms to the MKAnnotation class.  So I did that, but when I try to add it to the location, I do not see its annotationView in the viewForAnnotation delegate method.  That method is here:

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)theMapView viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation {
    static NSString *placeMarkIdentifier = @"SimplePinIdentifier";
    if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[AddressAnnotation class]]) {
        MKPinAnnotationView *annotationView = (MKPinAnnotationView *)[theMapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:placeMarkIdentifier];
        if (annotationView == nil) {
            annotationView = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:placeMarkIdentifier];
        }
        else {
            annotationView.annotation = annotation;
        }
        annotationView.enabled = YES;
        annotationView.animatesDrop = YES;
        annotationView.draggable = YES;
        annotationView.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorPurple;
        annotationView.canShowCallout = YES;


        // Create a button for the annotation
//        UIButton *rightArrowButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
//        annotationView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = rightArrowButton;
//        [self performSelector:@selector(openCallout:) withObject:annotation afterDelay:0.5];
        return annotationView;
    }
    return nil;

}
```

So I guess my questions are, do I need to create my own  object to do this, am I on the right track, what am I doing wrong, and why is it that in one case, I am adding a MKPlacemark object, and then if I do it the way other way, I add a  object, but not necessarily a subclass of MKPlacemark.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, the reason you're probably not seeing the annotation view when you use a custom annotation object (ie. `AddressAnnotation`) is that its `coordinate` is not being set (and so it's appearing at 0,0).

In the `placeMarkFromString` method, the code sets a lot of properties of the `AddressAnnotation` but not the `coordinate` and so the annotation is not appearing where expected.

If you set the `coordinate`, it will appear where expected and with the animation.

Regarding the other question as to why you see no animation when using an `MKPlacemark`:

By default, the map view will create an `MKPinAnnotationView` with a red pin but with `animatesDrop` set to `NO`.

So in `viewForAnnotation`, you have to explicitly do it for `MKPlacemark` just like you are for `AddressAnnotation`.

If all your annotations will be using `MKPinAnnotationView`, instead of checking for each different class of annotation you will be creating, you can flip the condition around by returning `nil` at the top of the method when the annotation class is `MKUserLocation` and then run the rest of the code without any class-checking (ie. returning `MKPinAnnotationView` with `animatesDrop` set to `YES` in all other cases).